# Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response while sending a ajax call to a outside server

Tags: ajax, cors, http-headers, cross-domain, watson-conversation

I am trying to make an ajax request for getting chat response from IBM Watson.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>ChatBox</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var dataText;
function testfunction(){
 var username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 var password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

 $.ajax({
     url: "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/b8120041-5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXb250/message?version=2018-02-16",
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
     },
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     processData: false,
     data: "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello\"}}",
     success: function (data) {
      dataText = data['output']['text'];
      console.log(dataText);
     },
     error: function(){
       alert("Cannot get data");
     }
 });
}
</script>
<button type ="radio" onclick = "testfunction();"> Generate json</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('pid').innerHTML = dataText">Get Json</button>                                       
<p id="pid">Hello i am inside p</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error-

Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

However, if I used a CORS chrome extension then I am got a proper response.

I have seen many solutions to the similar problem, and they asked to add some header on the server side. but here I don't have any control over the Watson server.

Please suggest me any solution for getting proper response for ajax request without using the extension.

To sum up, i want solution for

Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Is that your real username and password...?

Comment: I have removed the real credentials

Answer (score 0):

Create a page/control which will send a request to the target site and output the response as a page where you need it. This way you will see the page displayed, but you will need to fix the paths of `script`, `link`, `img` and `a` tags.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ANKITKUMAR do you use a server-side language?

Comment: I have already posted the whole code in the question. It is just HTML and jquery.

Comment: @ANKITKUMAR I repeat my question: do you use a server-side language? I have seen your code, but my question is different.

Comment: No, I haven't used any server-side language in this.

Comment: @ANKITKUMAR I suggest that you should use a server-side language and use that for sending the request, that will work around browser origin policy.